# How to solve this system of non-linear equations.

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

$$\begin{cases}2x-y^2=0\\
4y^3-2yx-3z=0\\
3z^2-3y=0 \end{cases}$$

I know the solutions are $(0,0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},1,1)$ but I just don't know how to manipulate the equations to obtain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the first equation we get
$$x=\frac{y^2}{2}$$ plugging this in the second equation we get
$$4y^3-y^3=z$$ or $$3y^3=z$$ plugging this in the last equation we obtain
$$y^6-y=0$$
factorizing
$$y(y^5-1)=0$$ therefor $$y=0$$ or $$y=1$$
can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes!, thank you.